# how to make that the server trust client side validation?

Tags: forms, html, tornado

i found sometimes -said- that *an application must have two validation: client side and server side*.

my question: is there any way to make a kind of trusting message that is crypted, so only the server and client will understand, so like that the server will avoid form verification, because when i've added regex to validation in python, this increased my application reponse time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you use the "crypted trusting message" there is no guarantee that message is even legitimate when coming from the client-side. 
You should always validate on the client-side so the user will not have to wait for the server response to be informed something is incorrect in the form just submitted.
You MUST always validate any input from the client on the server-side. If your regex is slow that only mean it's not efficient. You need to work on improving that instead.

Comment: so there is ALWAYS a server-side! in the new keygen element in html5, why not using this technique to crypt the "ok, it is validate, trust me" using the keygen technique? it will be useful no?

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp, actually if you will use public - private key pair, you will reinvent server session in the end. work on regexp.

Comment: @NikolayFominyh so hope they'll implement this on final HTML5 since it's still in the draft mode ;)